# Code error for contour anlaysis in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

I'm trying to use emgu.cv lib for contour function in vb.net. The problem is my var is not defined. This should come under lib emgu.cv which I have already imported.

```
Dim borderPen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 255, 0))
Dim processor As ImageProcessor

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim borderPen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(150, 0, 255, 0))

    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        For Each contour As var In processor.contours
            If contour.Total > 1 Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Red, contour.ToArray())
            End If
        Next
    End If

    SyncLock processor.foundTemplates
        For Each found As FoundTemplateDesc In processor.foundTemplates
            If found.template.name.EndsWith(".png") OrElse    found.template.name.EndsWith(".jpg") Then
                DrawAugmentedReality(found, e.Graphics)
                Continue For
            End If
        Next
    End SyncLock
End Sub

Private Sub DrawAugmentedReality(found As FoundTemplateDesc, gr As Graphics)
    Dim fileName As String = "C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A56.jpg"
    Dim AugmentedRealityImages As New Dictionary(Of String, Image)()
    Dim img As Image = AugmentedRealityImages(fileName)
    Dim p As Point = found.sample.contour.SourceBoundingRect.Center()
    Dim state = gr.Save()
    gr.TranslateTransform(p.X, p.Y)
    gr.RotateTransform(CSng(180.0F * found.angle / Math.PI))
    gr.ScaleTransform(CSng(found.scale), CSng(found.scale))
    gr.DrawImage(img, New Point(-img.Width / 2, -img.Height / 2))
    gr.Restore(state)
End Sub
```

I could not compile as var is not defined. How to fix this problem?

Comment: sorry i don't have the `dll` for run this i will check the code if you refer the link to download the `dll`

Comment: I used this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C) from the source code files i copied the dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the [Type <typename> is not defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy234eat.aspx) error because the type `var` is not defined. You fix this by doing one of the following steps:

- Remove **As var**.

```vb
For Each contour In processor.contours
```

- Replace **var** with the correct data type.

```vb
For Each contour As <THE_CORRECT_TYPE> In processor.contours
```

---

**Emgu**

Looking at the [source code](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=196168) for `emgu` *(written in C#)*, the `ImageProcessor.cs` file will reveal the data type of `contours`:

```cs
public List<Contour<Point>> contours;
```

Translated into vb.net:

```vb
Public contours As List(Of Contour(Of Point))
```

**Solution**

So with this information it's pretty easy to pick the correct data type.

```vb
For Each contour As Contour(Of Point) In Me.processor.contours
```

Note: You should *always* have [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) set to `On`.

Comment: var should be member in class Emgu.CV.Contour<T>where T: struct T is System.Drawing.Point
but in my codings, it is not defined into this class. how do i fix it. As I already import the Emgu.CV lib.

Comment: do you know how to define var under the lib Emgu.CV.Contour<T>where T: struct T.

Comment: @Saranya Have you written this code yourself or is this translated C# code? looks like your source is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967229/how-to-merging-and-join-two-contours-in-emgucv). Read: [var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Comment: yeap I translated it from C#. I got no knowledge in using emgu.cv lib via vb.net. my source is from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196168/Contour-Analysis-for-Image-Recognition-in-C)

Comment: your method for removing doesn't work. i have read the link. the problem is my var is not declared as string nor integer. var's defination should show emgu.cv lib. hope you get this. i have been stuck woth this error for the past weeks.